# How to fill array of type image with images from a folder c# store app

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I'm trying to create a game with cards and I want to put them in an array of type `Image` but the problem is that I want to fill it with 52 .png files from a folder (Assets/Cards). How can I do that? I know I must use Storage Folder but I can't seem to figure it out and I will be glad if someone can help me out. All I have is just an empty array.

```
void DeckCard()
{
    Image[] Deck = new Image[52];
    for (int i = 1; i <= Deck.Length; i++)
    {
        Deck[i] = new Image();
        Deck[i].Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(Deck[i]);
        Deck[i].Height = 200;
        Deck[i].Width = 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would use a database file or maybe xml file to store the images as byte arrays. Byte array is fairly easy to bounce around, store and draw to an image. That way you don't need to store 52 image files, just one data file.

Comment: i want to use image array im not in common with database file's and byte array's

Answer (score 0):

You can use the static method of abstract class `System.Drawing.Image` class to load the file and get the object of image `FromFile`

> Image.FromFile();

try below -

```
List<Image> imagelist = new List<Image>();

foreach (FileInfo oneFile in new DirectoryInfo("").GetFiles())
{
    imagelist.Add(Image.FromFile(oneFile.FullName));
}
```

Comment: i cant use "Directory" it's a windows store app